# Merging two Regular Expressions to Truncate Words in Strings

Tags: php, regex, string, truncate, multibyte

I'm trying to come up with the following function that truncates string to whole words (if possible, otherwise it should truncate to chars):

```
function Text_Truncate($string, $limit, $more = '...')
{
    $string = trim(html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    if (strlen(utf8_decode($string)) > $limit)
    {
        $string = preg_replace('~^(.{1,' . intval($limit) . '})(?:\s.*|$)~su', '$1', $string);

        if (strlen(utf8_decode($string)) > $limit)
        {
            $string = preg_replace('~^(.{' . intval($limit) . '}).*~su', '$1', $string);
        }

        $string .= $more;
    }

    return trim(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true));
}
```

Here are some tests:

```
// Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn and then the quick brown fox... (49 + 3 chars)
echo dyd_Text_Truncate('Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn and then the quick brown fox jumped overly the lazy dog and one day the lazy dog humped the poor fox down until she died.', 50, '...');

// Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn_and_then_the_quick_brown_fox_...  (50 + 3 chars)
echo dyd_Text_Truncate('Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn_and_then_the_quick_brown_fox_jumped_overly_the_lazy_dog and one day the lazy dog humped the poor fox down until she died.', 50, '...');
```

They both work as it is, however if I drop the second `preg_replace()` I get the following:

> Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn_and_then_the_quick_brown_fox_jumped_overly_the_lazy_dog
>   and one day the lazy dog humped the
>   poor fox down until she died....

I can't use `substr()` because it only works on byte level and I don't have access to `mb_substr()` ATM, I've made several attempts to join the second regex with the first one but without success.

Please help S.M.S., I've been struggling with this for almost an hour.

---

**EDIT: I'm sorry, I've been awake for 40 hours and I shamelessly missed this:**

```
$string = preg_replace('~^(.{1,' . intval($limit) . '})(?:\s.*|$)?~su', '$1', $string);
```

Still, if someone has a more optimized regex (or one that ignores the trailing space) please share:

```
"Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn and then "
"Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn_and_then_"
```

**EDIT 2: I still can't get rid of the trailing whitespace, can someone help me out?**

**EDIT 3: Okay, none of my edits did really work, I was being fooled by RegexBuddy - I should probably leave this to another day and get some sleep now. Off for today.**

Comment: Why don't you use `trim` to get rid of the trailing whitespace?

Comment: Awake for 40 hours and dealing with regex. +1 pity vote.

Comment: @Jens: Jesus... I should really get some sleep! :S

Comment: What's the point of removing the trailing whitespace if any (after 50-3 chars)? It would indicate the complete word (before) and would ensure your truncation is always of equal length.
So then: 

     '/(?<=.{47}).{3,}$/

would do it!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I can give you a happy morning after a long night of RegExp nightmares:

```
'~^(.{1,' . intval($limit) . '}(?<=\S)(?=\s)|.{'.intval($limit).'}).*~su'
```

Boiling it down:

```
^      # Start of String
(       # begin capture group 1
 .{1,x} # match 1 - x characters
 (?<=\S)# lookbehind, match must end with non-whitespace 
 (?=\s) # lookahead, if the next char is whitespace, match
 |      # otherwise test this:
 .{x}   # got to x chars anyway.
)       # end cap group
.*     # match the rest of the string (since you were using replace)
```

You could always add the `|$` to the end of `(?=\s)` but since your code was already checking that the string length was longer than the `$limit`, I didn't feel that case would be neccesary.

Comment: More a "happy afternoon" but thanks gnarf! I went to sleep having the impression that I would have to use lookahead or just use `trim()`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using wordwrap? (https://www.php.net/wordwrap)

Comment: Yes, it's way slower for big strings and doesn't work with multi-byte chars.