# How to split a long string without breaking words?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, split

I'm looking for something along the line of

```
str_split_whole_word($longString, $x)
```

Where `$longString` is a collection of sentences, and `$x` is the character length for each line. It can be fairly long, and I want to basically split it into multiple lines in the form of an array.

For example:

```
$longString = 'I like apple. You like oranges. We like fruit. I like meat, also.';
$lines = str_split_whole_word($longString, $x);
```

Desired output:

```
$lines = Array(
    [0] = 'I like apple. You'
    [1] = 'like oranges. We'
    [2] = and so on...
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code avoid breaking words, you won't get it using wordwrap().

The maximum length is defined using `$maxLineLength`. I've done some tests and it works fine.

```
$longString = 'I like apple. You like oranges. We like fruit. I like meat, also.';

$words = explode(' ', $longString);

$maxLineLength = 18;

$currentLength = 0;
$index = 0;

foreach ($words as $word) {
    // +1 because the word will receive back the space in the end that it loses in explode()
    $wordLength = strlen($word) + 1;

    if (($currentLength + $wordLength) <= $maxLineLength) {
        $output[$index] .= $word . ' ';
        $currentLength += $wordLength;
    } else {
        $index += 1;
        $currentLength = $wordLength;
        $output[$index] = $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. It removes spaces from between some words.

Comment: Was this answer ever correct?  It generates Warnings and mangles the output!  https://3v4l.org/Ref5f

Answer (score 65):

The easiest solution is to use [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap), and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) on the new line, like so:

```
$array = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $str, $x));
```

Where `$x` is a number of characters to wrap the string on.

Comment: This would work great if you don't already have line breaks in the string.

Comment: Perfect for CLI output of an error! Thnx

Comment: Multibyte safe version of worwrap function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229365/1203805 to work with non-ascii strings

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score 14):

Use [`wordwrap()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) to insert the linebreaks, then `explode()` on those linebreaks:

```
// Wrap at 15 characters
$x = 15;
$longString = 'I like apple. You like oranges. We like fruit. I like meat, also.';
$lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($longString, $x));

var_dump($lines);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "I like apple."
  [1]=>
  string(8) "You like"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "oranges. We"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "like fruit. I"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "like meat,"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "also."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This whole task can be accomplished with just one `preg_` function call instead of indirectly injecting a bunch of newlines and then splitting on those.

1. Match any character between zero and `$maxLength` times.
2. Forget/Release the matched characters from #1 with `\K`.
3. Match the next one or more whitespace characters or the end of the string.  The characters/position matched here will be consumed in the splitting process and will not appear in the output array.
4. Set the `preg_` function to exclude the empty element that is produced by splitting on the end of string position with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oovpq))

```
$longString = 'I like apple. You like oranges. We like fruit. I like meat, also.';
$maxLength = 18;

var_export(
    preg_split("/.{0,{$maxLength}}\K(?:\s+|$)/", $longString, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'I like apple. You',
  1 => 'like oranges. We',
  2 => 'like fruit. I like',
  3 => 'meat, also.',
)
```

If your input string might contain newlines, then just add the `s` pattern modifier.
`/.{0,{$maxLength}}\K(?:\s+|$)/s`  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5SgOt))