# PHP - Split string in array after X characters without cut word on limit

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode, word-wrap

I'm trying to split a string after x characters and put it in array. But I need to don't cut word if x is in a middle of a word. What I expect is to split on the word inferior.

I Tried this :

**CODE**

```
$string = "Helllooooo I'mmm <strong>theeeeee</strong> <em> woooooorrd</em> theeee loooonnngessttt";
$desired_width = 24;

$str = wordwrap($string, $desired_width, "\n");

var_dump($str);
die;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
string 'Helllooooo I'mmm
<strong>theeeeee</strong>
<em> woooooorrd</em>
theeee loooonnngessttt' (length=86)
```

How to put it in array ? Is there another method to do that ? a mix between this and explode() ? thanks !

Comment: Why not just explode it now with "\n" as delimiter?!

Comment: You need to take a shot to regular expressions, and/or DOM functions in PHP.

Comment: yes a mix of it `explode`, you said it right

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254787/php-split-a-long-string-without-breaking-words

Comment: thanks all ! I did that : `$str = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, $desired_width));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Helllooooo I'mmm <strong>theeeeee</strong> <em> woooooorrd</em> theeee loooonnngessttt";
$desired_width = 24;

$str = wordwrap($string, $desired_width, "\n");
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
var_dump($arr);
die;
```

Comment: I did that too (5 minutes ago before) :) thanks ! `$str = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, $desired_width));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$string = "Helllooooo I'mmm <strong>theeeeee</strong> <em> woooooorrd</em> theeee loooonnngessttt";
$desired_width = 24;

$str = wordwrap($string, $desired_width, "***");
$str = explode("***",$str);
var_dump($str);
die;
```

the output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Helllooooo I'mmm"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "<strong>theeeeee</strong>"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "<em> woooooorrd</em>"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "theeee loooonnngessttt"
}
```

Comment: Huff, good thing OP doesn't have a few asterix in their string!

Comment: You need to use any text or symbol that is not expected to exist in the string as split point.

the problem  appears if the string is dynamic and it contains many stars (in this case) or a new line ' /n'  (in the previous solution ).