# Split a string into two equal length parts using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, explode

I need to split a string into two equal length parts.String can contain blank spaces, commas or anything. I have referred and tries the code sample of explode statement from the link http://www.testingbrain.com/php-tutorial/php-explode-split-a-string-by-string-into-array.html but there it not showing any sample for splitting by equal length.

One more thing, while splitting words shouldn't broken.

Comment: Is there any default function available in PHP for this ?

Comment: Without breaking word, how you will make exact half??

Comment: If you want to split string without breaking words, look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11256141/4832775

Answer (score 4):

This will split without breaking the word, at the most possible half of the text, but it may split at any other characters (`,`,`.`,`@` etc)

```
$data = "Split a string by length without breaking word"; //string

if (strlen($data) % 2 == 0) //if lenhth is odd number
    $length = strlen($data) / 2;
else
    $length = (strlen($data) + 1) / 2; //adjust length

for ($i = $length, $j = $length; $i > 0; $i--, $j++) //check towards forward and backward for non-alphabet
{
    if (!ctype_alpha($data[$i - 1])) //forward
    {
        $point = $i; //break point
        break;
    } else if (!ctype_alpha($data[$j - 1])) //backward
    {
        $point = $j; //break point
        break;
    }
}
$string1 = substr($data, 0, $point);
$string2 = substr($data, $point);
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

```
$str="Test string";
$middle=strlen($str)/2;
$first=substr($str,0,$middle);
$last=substr($str,$middle);
```

Comment: this isn't solving the problem of split words.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is are good start:

```
$string = "My name is StackOcerflow and I like programming, one more comma. Next sentance.";
$words = preg_split( "/( )/", $string );
print_r($words);

$length = 0;
foreach($words as $word){
    $length += strlen($word);
}

$string_new = "";
$string_new2 = "";
$length_half = 0;
foreach($words as $word){
    $length_half += strlen($word);
    if($length_half >= ($length/2)){
        $string_new2 .= $word . ' ';
    }else{
        $string_new .= $word . ' ';
    }
}
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo 'Full=' . $string . '<br/>';
echo 'First=' . $string_new . '<br/>';
echo 'Second=' . $string_new2 . '<br/>';
echo 'First length=' . strlen($string_new) . '<br/>';
echo 'Second=' . strlen($string_new2) . '<br/>';
```