# Divide string into words

Tags: php, regex

I'm now having a headache solving this issue.

I have this line :-

```
$quote = "Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm.";
```

How do I break this line such that each broken line would have **max 27 characters?**

My Desired output would be

```
array(line 1) --> Success consists of going
array(line 2) --> from failure to failure 
array(line 3) --> without loss of enthusiasm
```

This is what I've tried :-

```
$final_lines = array();
      //conver to string array
      $string_arrray_line = str_split($string_line);
      $a = "";
      $b=0;
      $counter = 0;
      for($i=0;$i<strlen($string_line);$i++)
      {
        // echo $i;
        if($counter == 27)
        {
          //insert into array now
          $final_lines[$b] = $a;
          $b++;
          $a = "";
          $counter = 0;
        }
        $a .= $string_arrray_line[$i];
        $counter++;
        // var_dump($string_arrray_line[$i]);
      }
```

^^  This doesn't work and dozen other solutions that I tried.
What could I possibly do to achieve what I want?

Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: You might also want to see [PHP: split a long string without breaking words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254787)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [wordwrap()](http://php.net/wordwrap):

```
<?php
$quote = "Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm.";
$result = explode("\n", wordwrap($quote, 27));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I'm now banging my head against the wall. Thanks mate.