# PHP wordwrap into 2 variables

Tags: php

Using `wordwrap` so that I can get whole words, how can I split a string of upto 255 characters into two line variables of 45 characters and ignore the rest?

I would use:

```
$line1 = substr($str, 0, 45);
$line2 = substr($str, 45, 45);
```

But I need the break to be a a word, not the 45th character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: split a long string without breaking words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254787/php-split-a-long-string-without-breaking-words)

Comment: Agreed, but I must say that my question and the answer I'm waiting to accept are very succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php),

```
$lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($str, 45, "\n"));
```

Comment: Great. Then I'll just use `$lines[0]` and `$lines[1]` - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

php `wardwrap` is the function you should try.

[wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 45, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
```

Or by using both explode and wordwrap,

```
$x = 15;
$longString = 'I like apple. You like oranges. We like fruit. I like meat, also.';
$lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($longString, $x));

var_dump($lines);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "I like apple."
  [1]=>
  string(8) "You like"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "oranges. We"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "like fruit. I"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "like meat,"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "also."
}
```

You can now use first 2 values from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the space after or before the 45th character with `strpos(string,find,start)` like `strpos($string, " ", 45)`. Or find all delimiter (space,"!","." etc) characters with regex and then carry on the query according to maths.

```
$subject = "abcdef sdfasdfa hdfghdfgh...";
$pattern = '/[\s\n\b!.]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 45);
print_r($matches);
```

But take into consideration that it will cut, for example until 51th character if it finds the delimiter there.