# UTF-8 decoding umlauts failing occasionally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8

Ok, this is strange and I don't really know what causes my problem:

**Workflow:**

- I've a regular mysql database with an utf-8 column.
- I'm inserting rows, via a simple input field, text with german umlauts into this column.
- I'm reading and displaying the rows with a simple query.

**My Problem:**

Sometimes, and only sometimes, instead of the umlauts question marks are being displayed.
What's weird is that it's only with certain words, not all of the umlauts.
For instance: "Gummibären" results in a question mark for the "ä" but "Gumibären" (note the single "m") is being displayed correctly. So, I can't really figure out a pattern here.

- The column is in `utf8_general_ci`
- The HTML-Files uses the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
- The PHP-File itself is encoded in utf-8

The query is:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
$var = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC";
```

What's also strange is, that the "ä" is not replaced by 1 question mark but 2 question marks, as if there were 2 characters not encoded instead of just 1.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Warning - mysql_query
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 encoded html pages show � (questions marks) instead of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-%ef%bf%bd-questions-marks-instead-of-characters)

Comment: From the above linked QA, "If the data is being fetched from a database, you could use mb_detect_encoding() to verify its encoding."

Comment: Thanks, I read this post and did some researching. Unfortunately it doesn't help me a lot with my problem. Weirdly every other occurrence of a certain umlaut is displayed right and not as a �.
If I'm setting mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); it's displaying 2 �� if not, it's displaying a single �.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding shows ASCII

Comment: After some testing, it seems even weirder because it only happens if one of the umlauts or other extended latin characters is at place 7 of a string. For example 123456ä89 results in the ä being a question mark whereas 12345ä789 (6th place) displays normal. Sorry for language but: WTF.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It had not really anything to do with reading or writing utf into the database but with the PHP function `wordwrap()`. If `wordwrap()` is used with multi-byte unicode characters such as "ä" and similar, it will mess up strings.
I figured it out with the help of this: [Multi-byte safe wordwrap() function for UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825226/multi-byte-safe-wordwrap-function-for-utf-8) and this: [php wordwrap cut parameter when dealing with weird characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527880/php-wordwrap-cut-parameter-when-dealing-with-weird-characters) – for future reference.

Thanks though for your input!