# How to cut off multi-byte string (English word and Chinese character) in PHP?

Tags: php, multibyte, chinese-locale

I have this function works *not quite* well in PHP 5.2.0, this function cut string into desired length :

```
function neat_trim($str, $n, $delim='...')
{
    $len = strlen($str);

    if ($len > $n)
    {
        preg_match('/(.{' . $n . '}.*?)\b/', $str, $matches);
        return rtrim($matches[1]) . $delim;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

And I call

```
$multibyte_string = "Portion of Chicken for 1 person<br>一人份鸡肉";

echo neat_trim($multibyte_string,42) . "</br>";
```

Will produce

```
Portion of Chicken for 1 person
一人�...
```

Unfortunately it won't work on PHP-5.4.29, it will produce:

```
...
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825226/multi-byte-safe-wordwrap-function-for-utf-8) but didn't work. Please help.

Comment: If this is *utf-8* 1.) `$len = strlen($str);` use `mb_strlen($str, "utf-8");` the char length is **40** not **50** [mbstring extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) needed. 2.) If it's unicode use `u` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and probably also `s` flag is wanted in your regex for making the dot also match newlines: `'/(.{' . $n . '}.*?)\b/us'`

Comment: Thanks @Jonny, your comment is really help me. I'm new in handling multi character in PHP. I posted my working code.

Comment: Answers go in the answer box below, not in the question.

Comment: I don't think "一人�..." is a particularly positive outcome. I wouldn't call this "it works".

Comment: @deceze OK, it's not quite well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multibyte trim in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php)

Comment: @Seto would replace tags from `$multibyte_string` with space before processing. The word boundary `\b` can and will break html tags. [See here with few modifications](http://pastebin.com/kmMiHF5g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code based on @Jonny's comment, thanks again**

```
function neat_trim($str, $n, $delim='...')
{
    $len = mb_detect_encoding($str) == "UTF-8" ? mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8") : strlen($str);
    if ($len > $n)
    {
        preg_match('/(.{' . $n . '}.*?)\b/us', $str, $matches);
        return rtrim($matches[1]) . $delim;
    }
    return $str;
}
```