# PHP: UTF-8 multi-byte string splitter?

Tags: php, string, splitter

Can this work for splitting a multi-byte string every ten characters?

```
$string = 'Star Wars Episode Seven Sucked';    
mb_split('.', $string, 10);
```

The PHP manual says that `str_split()` works on bytes, not characters in multi-byte strings. That means `mb_split()` would seem to be a natural "overloaded" substitution, but the two functions (`str_split()` and `mb_split()`) have different function signatures and are not "overload buddies," so to speak. Then, I had a thought, what about this?

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$string = 'Star Wars Episode Seven Sucked';  
$tokens = [];

for($i = 0, $length = mb_strlen($string); $i < $length; $i += 10)
{
    $tokens[] = mb_substr($string, $i, 10, 'UTF-8');
}

print_r($tokens);
```

Comment: Are you searching for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3825226/3933332 ?

Comment: I'm confused why you're asking this instead of just test it yourself?  Or reading [mb_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) ?

Comment: @devlincarnate I see. I refer you to the definition of the Stackoverflow site.

Comment: Good question. Nothing wrong with this question at all.

Comment: Why should she? Maybe she's not somewhere she cannot code right now?

Comment: @Rizier123 No. I am not.

Comment: @RyanVincent You need to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @I am on a train and I had a thought. Sorry if that is not good enough for some.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/rBAZV

Comment: I believe this question is good. +1

Answer (score -1):

```
function mb_utf8_split($string, $interval)
{
     $tokens = [];
     mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

     $stringEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true);

     if(!$stringEncoding)
     {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unable to identify character encoding.");
     }

     if($stringEncoding !== 'UTF-8')
     {
          $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', $stringEncoding);
     }

     for($i = 0, $length = mb_strlen($string); $i < $length; $i += $interval)
     {
         $tokens[] = mb_substr($string, $i, $interval, 'UTF-8');
     }

     return $tokens;
}
```

Comment: This could probably be better.

Comment: This is a good attempt. I'm not sure about the `mb_detect_encoding()` line's second parameter (`'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1'`), but it looks like a good start to me.